# Completeness axiom to find a least and greatest element

Tags: real-analysis

I have a solution for the following question.

*Let $L$ and $U$ be nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{R}=L\cup U$ and such that for each $l$ in $L$ and each $u$ in $U$, we have $l<u$. Then, either $L$ has a greatest element or $U$ has a least element.*

The solution is as follows.

*$L$ is bounded above so it has a least upper bound $l_0$. Similarly, $U$ is bounded below so it has a greatest lower bound $u_0$. If $l_0 \in L$, then it is the greatest element in $L$. Otherwise, $l_0 \in U$ and $u_0 \leq l_0$. If $u_0 < l_0$, then there exists $l \in L$ with $u_0 < l$. Thus $l$ is a lower bound for $U$ and is greater than $u_0$. Contradiction. Hence $u_0 = l_0$ so $u_0 \in U$ and it is the least element in $U$.*

My question is, how do we conclude that *If $u_0 < l_0$, then there exists $l \in L$ with $u_0 < l$*?

Comment: Suppose there were no such $l$. Then $l\le u_0$ for all $l\in L$, so $u_0$ is an upper bound but $u_0<l_0$ so this contradicts choice of $l_0$ as the "least" upper bound

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $l_0$ is the least upper bound of $L,$ then by definition, any number $x$ strictly less than $l_0$ fails to be an upper bound of $L.$ In particular, if $u_0<l_0,$ then $u_0$ is not an upper bound of $L,$ and so there is some $l\in L$ such that $u_0<l.$

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense. I have another question. Where in the proof do we use the fact that $\mathbb{R}=L \cup U$?

Comment: @Teodorism at the step: "otherwise, $l_0 \in U$"