# A equivalent statement of completeness of axiom

Tags: real-analysis

The following is a property on $\mathbb{R}$ (We don't assume least upper bound property here):
*Let $L$ and $U$ be any nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and such that for each $l$ in $L$ and each $u$ in $U$, we have $l<u$. And $L \cup U = \mathbb{R}$. Then, either $L$ has a greatest element or $U$ has a least element.*

If $\mathbb{R}$ has the above property, does this mean $\mathbb{R}$ has the least upper bound property?

Alternatively, can we prove this property is equivalent to the least upper bound property?
See also: [The converse holds](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2010866/549321).

EDIT:

Note that it's **NOT** cut property: , [see](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1721305/549321)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is clear that $\mathbb{R}$ does not have the property you describe. Consider what happens when we remove a point from $\mathbb{R}$. For example, set $L := (- \infty, 0)$ and $U := (0, \infty)$. Neither $L$ nor $U$ has a least element nor a greatest element.

However, if we had this property, we would necessarily have completeness as well. Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}$ be bounded above for some ordered set $A$. Set $L := \{a \in A \: : \: \text{there is $x \in X$ with $a \leq x$} \}$, and set $U := A \setminus L$. Then there is some point $b \in A$ such that $b$ is either a maximum for $L$ or a minumum for $U$. In either case, we have that $b$ is a least upper bound for $X$.

Comment: when $b$ is a maximum for $L$, how to prove it is a least upper bound, this is the most difficult part for me.

Comment: Actually, I think is impossible to prove if we don't assume some assumptions that it is a  densely ordered set.

Comment: If $b$ is the maximum element of $L$, then $b \in L$ and $x \leq b$ for all $x \in L$. The second condition makes it a least upper bound. If $y$ is another upper bound, we can break it into cases. If $y \in L$, then $y = b$. If $y \not \in L$, then $b < y$.